# my personal web history seen by my school

Tags: network

can my school or family know what I do on my home laptop which  my dad  gave and also has many of his ex company's information but I logged of everything can my school still see anything

Comment: Are you using the laptop only at home? Is any special software from the school installed on the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

## school

Possibly. They would need a purpose-built software to be downloaded and run on the computer, but such softwares *do* exist and I am aware of at least two video-conferencing softwares that allow downloading and running third-party software; I have actually used one of those to remotely diagnose a laptop. Normally, you would be required to approve the download and run of the software, or some kind of "remote assistance" call.

This, by the way, is also a trick used by some scammers that will try and convince you that [the computer got infected](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/how-spot-avoid-and-report-tech-support-scams) or needs diagnosing. The "diagnosis" program will actually browse the whole disk, even after the call has terminated, looking for passwords, bank accounting information and the like.

## family

You just ask "can", i.e. "is it possible?". So I have to answer: **YES**. If that was *my* laptop that I gave to you, even after logging out of whatever, I could still know whatever happened on that computer.

"Physical access trumps all security", and if that was your father's laptop, he had the required physical access. In my line of work, if an untrusted party has had access to a computer, that computer is considered compromised no matter what. Depending on circumstances, not even a full format and reinstall might be deemed enough (I no longer work in *those* circumstances, but just by way of example, [you can tap an external keyboard in just one second](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F8YJ6DK). Many other such tricks exist).

## network

Actually, if you used the laptop at home, connected to *my* WiFi router, not even HTTPS could save you (HTTPS plus [some plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkmyhttps/) *might*. I would *still* know what sites you visited, if not the content you downloaded).

And the same applies if you connected to the school's network, or to the school VPN if there is one. In that case, whoever owns the network equipment owns your navigation history, because *you navigated through their equipment*. Your browser *asked politely* the VPN servers to forward a request for navigation, and those servers might well have recorded the request even if your browser did not, or forgot. The "network" scenario also potentially trumps things like "incognito mode" and "Private Navigation".

## it *can* happen. *Does* it happen?

The real question is how likely this is. Doing it unbeknownst to you would be **illegal** on the part of the school almost anywhere in the world. So, unless you were asked to download and/or run something and complied, no, it probably didn't happen.

The same applies for a lot of other "fingerprinting" and sensing techniques.

For the family, your opinion is better than mine. It comes down to trust and computer savviness. If your parents ask you how to configure the printer, I'd say there is very little chance. If one of them works in IT or, worse, computer security, and has any reason to be curious about your digital whereabouts, well...